# Android Toast message not displaying, without any errors

Tags: android, android-toast

I want to add a toast message to my application, but it seems there is either some conflict or I might be doing something wrong.

For testing purposes I have posted the below code in more than one of my activities.

```
Toast test = Toast.makeText(ShareEventActivity.this, "Link has been copied!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        test.show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Application Context",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Base Context",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this,"this",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This does not work in any part of my application. It shows no error messages or warnings.

I can't seem to figure out what's happening and haven't found anything online. 
The only thing that I can think of is maybe a conflict is happening with a third party library.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.1.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.5'
compile 'org.droidparts:droidparts:2.9.8'
```

Theme used:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <!--<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>-->
        <!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>-->
        <!--<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>-->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>
```

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Please post code where u are using it...

Comment: Did you disable the notifications for this app ? Toast are considered as notifications.

Comment: maxoumime, Thanks a lot that was it, so basically toasts should not be used for sending a message.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you must use an activity to obtain the context for your toast. I had the same problem as you did when using a fragment as the context for my Toast.

My approach now is to pass a weak reference to my main activity into the fragment using a static newInstance method to create my fragment.

Then set the value of the weak reference in a newInstance method in your fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

   private WeakReference<MainActivity> mWeakRefActivity;

public static MyFragment newInstance(MainActivity activity, ...) {
   mWeakRefActivity = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(activity);
   ... // pass any other args or a a bundle to fragment here
}

Toast.makeText(mWeakRefActivity.get().getApplicationContext(), ...);
```

Then in your toast call use the weak reference to get the context

You also don't have to create an object to use your Toast - just call Toast.makeText directly without creating an object. Less code is better.

But what you show should work - without seeing the surrounding code it's impossible to say any more.